# how to make a navigation drawer inside fragment?

Tags: java, android

I want to make an app that has a bottom navigation with 3 menu, and each menu has a different fragment (BerandaFragment, JelajahFragment, and ProfilkuFragment). I want to put a navigation drawer in menu "profilku" which is thats a fragment (ProfilkuFragment). And this is my problem. When we make a navigation drawer the "controller" is always inside an activity. As we know that activity and fragment are different, so when I move the code from activity to fragment (ProfilkuFragment) there so much error. help me to solve this. I am sorry for my bad English I hope you guys understand what I mean. Thank you!

I've tried to add a navigation drawer activity and move the code from activity to fragment. And of course there so much error. I fix it as best I can. And yeah that's not work

ProfilkuFragment.java

```
public class ProfilkuFragment extends Fragment {


    public ProfilkuFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profilku, container, false);
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.navigation_beranda:
                        BerandaFragment berandaFragment = new BerandaFragment();
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentBerandaTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentBerandaTransaction.replace(R.id.content, berandaFragment);
                        fragmentBerandaTransaction.commit();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.navigation_jelajah:
                        JelajahFragment jelajahFragment = new JelajahFragment();
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentJelajahTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentJelajahTransaction.replace(R.id.content, jelajahFragment);
                        fragmentJelajahTransaction.commit();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.navigation_profilku:
                        ProfilkuFragment profilkuFragment = new ProfilkuFragment();
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentProfilkuTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentProfilkuTransaction.replace(R.id.content, profilkuFragment);
                        fragmentProfilkuTransaction.commit();
                        return true;
                }
```

I expect when I click "profilku" menu, PofilkuFragment will appear with a navigation drawer.

**this is screenshot when i click profilku menu:**

[image: image 1]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below link:-

https://gist.github.com/eirabben/46d81bd9db52325563c7

But as per my personal suggestion do not use navigation drawer in side menu, instead of please use this in activity and with that you can use bottom view also at that same time.